# Is it possible to have a vector of traits bounded by Sized?

Tags: rust

I am trying to see if there is any way to implement a vector of sized traits.
I know about trait objects, and using `Vec<Box<dyn traitName>>` if `traitName` is `?Sized`. But what if I have ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=43d9ee07cfe643d32a00963aa066c929)):

```rust
trait A: Sized {}

struct B {
    c: u64,
}

impl A for B {}

fn lol() -> Vec<A> {
    let mut a: Vec<A> = Vec::new();
    
    let b = B { c: 2} ;
    
    a.push(b);
    
    a
}
```

The error I get is:

```
error[E0782]: trait objects must include the `dyn` keyword
 --> src/main.rs:8:17
  |
8 | fn lol() -> Vec<A> {
  |                 ^
  |
help: add `dyn` keyword before this trait
  |
8 - fn lol() -> Vec<A> {
8 + fn lol() -> Vec<dyn A> {
```

but to fix that I have to use trait objects, which is not possible since `A: Sized`. Any way to fix this or is it impossible?

Comment: You don't. `trait A: Sized` is basically a big sign saying "Nobody is allowed to use this trait as a trait object. Ever." What you're doing with `Vec<A>` is *equivalent* to `Vec<dyn A>` (`dyn` was added as a keyword later and is now recommended for any use of trait objects; you should never write `Vec<A>` in modern Rust if `A` is a trait), which is already a trait object. The error is informing you that you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

`A` where `A` is a trait is just an old syntax (forbidden in the 2021 edition) to `dyn A`. You can't create `A` or `dyn A` if `A: Sized`, ever.

if you'll run this with the 2018 edition, [you'll get errors "the size for values of type `(dyn A + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time"](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4c500a0f1457254375fca81bf015bc57).